# IIS 8.0 Directory HttpRedirect

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, http-redirect, url-rewrite-module, iis-8

Is there a way in IIS to redirect the following request:
`http://mysite/report1/img/logo.png` to `http://mysite/myapplication/report1/images/logo.png` for ALL images in the img directory without having to explicitly map them individually?

Additional requirement- I have THOUSANDS of reports on a drive mapped to the 'report1' virtual directory- each with their own 'img' directory- so there is no reasonable way to use IIS manager to map those directories individually either.

I'm looking to see if there is some way to add a wildcard (or other) HttpRedirect in the IIS server web.config file to correctly map all the images for all the reports.  I tried:

```
<add wildcard="*res/img/" destination="/reporter/content/images/reportimages" />
```

But that seemed to have no effect.

EDIT: Some more research shows that using the URL Rewrite module might work... but so far I haven't gotten it to work.

My rule looks like this (in web.config):

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect rule1 for ImageRedirect">
        <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{ImageRedirect:{REQUEST_URI}}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="/res/img/(.+)" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP_HOST}/reporter/content/reporterimages/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
     </rule>
</rules>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track using the URL Rewrite module.
The most simple rule in your case would be:

```
<rule name="Rewrite images" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^/report1/img/(.+)$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/myapplication/report1/images/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

It does check if the requested url matches `^/report1/img/(.+)$` and if yes, trigger a rewrite to your new folder.

If you want to use a Redirect instead:

```
<rule name="Redirect images" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^/report1/img/(.+)$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/myapplication/report1/images/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

(If you don't specify it, by default a Redirect is permanent (301))

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  But I can't seem to get it to work.  Here's a real input url: `http://localhost/atlas/report-1.0.2/res/img/ctc.png` and the redirect url: `http://localhost/reporter/content/images/reportimages/ctc.png`.  It's like nothing is happening....?

Comment: Have you change the regex to `url="^atlas/report-1.0.2/res/img/(.+)$"`? Have you used the Rewrite or Redirect version?

Comment: I haven't changed the regex because that report-1.0.2 portion of the url will change.  The only consistent parts of the url are the host (`http://localhost`) and `/res/img/`.  I think I just need to change the match to "/res/img/(.+)$" rather than beginning (^).  It's seeming to work for one specific image url, but not for image url's embedded in a page... still working on it!

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Note that Redirect and Rewrite are 2 really different actions. If you still have the problem, update your question with your rules and errors and I will take a look.